# Input box onchange only allow numbers and one dot

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I am creating an input box with an onChange function that will check to see if the characters are only digits and only allow up to one period/dot '.'

The function I have here is not working:

```
function addPercentSeparator(n) {
  let str = n;
  let match = str.match(/\d*\.\d*/)
  if (match) {
    return str;
  }
}
```

I also tried: `let match = str.match(/^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)/)`

What I am trying to achieve is only allowing for one period.
If the user enters a number without a period, it will append a period to end of string when they click outside the input box.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/zLcf4S/1) regex is supposed to do the trick:

```
^\d*\.?\d*$
```

But if you'll ask me, I would make sure there are digits *before* the dot, using `^\d+\.?\d*$`.

**Explanation:**

- As the dot isn't mandatory, I've added the `?`, which symbolizes "0 or 1 occurrences".
- I've also added the `^` and the `$` to make sure no parts of the string will be matched if the whole string is illegal.

I hope this works for you!